# Starting up postgres automatically on OSX

Tags: macos, postgresql

Everytime I reboot my system (OSX - El Capitan), I can't access the `psql` shell any more.

```
> psql
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
  Is the server running locally and accepting
  connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

I have to first start the psql server manually with

```
pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres9.6 -l /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log start
```

and then it works.

What's the best way to have this run automatically on startup so I don't have to run it?

Thanks!

Comment: Check https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/46AE54A4.4040100@u.washington.edu

Comment: Did you install with homebrew? If so, this worked for me [https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-start-postgresql-server-on-mac-os-x/](https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-start-postgresql-server-on-mac-os-x/)